# Uploading and Downloading an encrypted object

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I am new to AWS Services and I am pulling my hair with this one:
I have a code which lets me upload and download objects in a bucket, but when I try to encrypt the bucket with the **AWS S3 SSE-KMS (the default option)** it seems like it does not work.

Currently I have this as my client:

```
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'credentials'    => $credentials,
    'region'         => 'eu-west-1',
    'version'        => 'latest',
]);

//Upload an object while using the Server Side Encryption:
$result = $s3->putObject([
    'Bucket'               => $bucket,
    'SourceFile'           => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], //Via a input type submit. (PHP Form)
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
]);
```

With those settings I should be able to putObject into my s3-encrypted bucket, but when I execute the order (putObject) the page stays waiting for something and can't finish the request.
What I am missing here? I would gladly take someone's advice.

Great community!

EDIT 1:
To upload an object encrypted by the ssk-kms key use

```
//Upload an object while using the Server Side Encryption:
$result = $s3->putObject([
    'Bucket'               => $bucket,
    'Key'                  => $key,
    'SourceFile'           => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], //Via a input type submit. (PHP Form)
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
]);
```

Trying to retrieve the encrypted object by using the `getObjectUrl` method:

```
echo $url = $s3->getObjectUrl($bucket, $folderUser);
```

But it retrieves an XML like,

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>1iejr93i2u5ka00</RequestId>
<HostId>fn3hhuFGYjkQI/sCeQVddddd631d213i21jidfeoihga45146363das40E=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Your putObject call is missing properties, most notably Key.

Comment: Hey @jarmod that was it, but now, If i get the url from the object I can't download it, cause it's encrypted. Do you know how can I download the encrypted object? Thanks...

Comment: You should add the code you’re using to get the URL for the object and how you’re attempting to download the object.

Comment: Ok @jarmod give me 2 minutes and will update the question with the code to retrieve the "download" link. Anyways, many thanks for staying here and answering my dumb questions, appreciate people like you :)

Comment: I have edited with the simple code I use to retrieve the url of the stored object. @jarmod

Comment: What is $folderUser? That parameter is supposed to be the object’s key (as you can see in the SDK docs). Also, FYI this method will only provide usable URLs for publicly readable objects (again, see docs)

Comment: Ok... so to download the object either make it Public-Readable with ACLs or find another way to download the object. Thanks @jarmod

Comment: If you want the object to be public then either make the object public via ACL or make the bucket public via bucket policy. If you need the object to remain private but still shareable via URL then create and shared a pre-signed URL. Don’t make things public that aren’t meant to be public.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod I finally got that. Appreciate the time and effort... This can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick summary of problems and solutions so this answer can be accepted:

1. the `putObject` call is missing `Key`, which is the S3 object key
2. the `getObjectUrl` call included `$folderUser`, which should instead be the S3 object key
3. to be able to use a URL returned by `getObjectUrl`, the object (or bucket) must be public
4. if you don't want the object to be public, create and share a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html) instead